# Deleting elements of a list with a condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list of number-pairs, like this `{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},...{y,z}}`. I need to delete some elements if its 2nd number is less than a threshold `thd`.

For example, using `DeleteCases[{{1, 3}, {2, 0.3}, {4, 0.02}}, #[[2]] < 0.1 &]`, I want to obtain `{{1, 3}, {2, 0.3}}`, but it does not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This also works `DeleteCases[{{1,3},{2,0.3},{4,0.02}},x_/;(x[[2]]<0.1)]` gives `{{1,3},{2,0.3}}`

Comment: It helps to read the documentation of the function one wants to use. Even if you are familiar with it, there are always interesting options that one may have overlooked.

Comment: The community is always happy to help you, but we may not want to keep this question open for long after you solve your problem. The reasoning is that we want to curate only questions and answers that can help future visitors., so your question may closed as it is technically off-topic. That is because it arises from a simple mistake easily found in the documentation and it's unlikely to help any future visitors. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning up policy. This one and all your future good questions are welcome.

Comment: `t = RandomReal[{-4, 4}, {20, 2}]` and `t /. {a_, b_} /; b < 0.5 -> {a}` would delete the second element only, assuming the `threshold = 0.5`. For deleting the whole element, use `t /. {a_, b_} /; b < 0.5 -> Nothing`.

Comment: @rhermans  I commend you for your thoughtful comment, with which I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)`[expr,pattern]` removes all elements of `expr` that match `pattern`. The second argument is a [pattern](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/guide/Patterns.html), not a [function](https://reference.wolframcloud.com/language/ref/Function.html). Your second argument is a function that working as a pattern does NOT match any of your data elements, so nothing gets deleted.

Try this

```
SeedRandom[42];
data=RandomReal[10,{10,2}]
(* {{4.25905,3.91023},{3.47069,4.53741},{5.55963,2.89169},{2.96848,2.06408},{3.2517,9.73325},{2.58796,5.50582},{7.17287,7.54353},{8.60349,9.96966},{7.39226,0.383646},{3.76127,2.96199}} *)

DeleteCases[data, {a_,b_/;b<4}]
(* {{3.47069,4.53741},{3.2517,9.73325},{2.58796,5.50582},{7.17287,7.54353},{8.60349,9.96966}} *)
```

or your example

```
DeleteCases[{{1, 3}, {2, 0.3}, {4, 0.02}},{a_,b_/;b<0.1}]
(* {{1,3},{2,0.3}} *)
```